# Using refinements to patch a core Module such as Kernel

Tags: ruby, refinements

I'm going through the Facets API and picking some methods to include in my refinement-compatible patch library.

I've hit a snag trying to patch Kernel. It's a module, whereas the other stuff I've patched has been classes (String, Array, etc.)

---

Here's proof that can't can't be refined using my standard approach for core classes:

```
module Patch
  refine Kernel do
    def patched?
      true
    end
  end
end

# TypeError: wrong argument type Module (expected Class)
# from (pry):16:in `refine'
```

---

I've also tried wrapping the Kernel module in a class, and changing the global reference to Kernel to that class.

```
class MyKernel
  include Kernel
  extend Kernel
end

# not sure if Object::Kernel is really the global reference
Object::Kernel = MyKernel

module Patch
  refine MyKernel do
    def patched?
      true
     end
  end
end

class Test
  using Patch
  patched?
end
# NoMethodError: undefined method `patched?' for Test:Class
# from (pry):15:in `<class:Test>'
```

---

In this case I could successfully get the same functionality by replacing Kernel with Object:

```
module Patch
  refine Object do
    def patched?
      true
     end
  end
end

class Test
  using Patch
  patched?
end
```

But I'm not sure if I could get this equivalency with other core modules such as Enumerable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33071443

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules can be refined as of [ruby 2.4](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/NEWS.html):

> `Module#refine` accepts a module as the argument now. [Feature [#12534](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12534)]

The old [caveat](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) ("Refinements only modify classes, not modules so the argument must be a class") no longer applies (although it wasn't removed from the documentation until [ruby 2.6](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)).

**Example**:

```rb
module ModuleRefinement
  refine Enumerable do
    def tally(&block)
      block ||= ->(value) { value }
      counter = Hash.new(0)
      each { |value| counter[block[value]] += 1 }
      counter
    end
  end
end

using ModuleRefinement

p 'banana'.chars.tally # => {"b"=>1, "a"=>3, "n"=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the question, one can perform the functional equivalent of extending the Kernel module by instead using the Object class.

The other example I gave was the Enumerable module, which it turns out can be practically extended through the Enumerator class:

```
module Patch
  refine Enumerator do
    def patched?
      true
    end
  end
end

class Test
  using Patch
  Array.new.to_enum.patched?
end
```

So I guess a workable solution could be to not try and turn core modules into classes, but instead extend classes that already include them.

In this case I could check with `Enumerator < Enumerable` which returns true because the Enumerator class includes the Enumerable module (though it doesn't check if it's been extended)

---

To update after looking at the [corefines](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jirutka/corefines) source, I found a helpful method for finding all the classes that include a Module

[classes_including_module](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jirutka/corefines/master/Corefines/Support#classes_including_module-class_method)